# How do I test https on socket.io locally?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've implemented an application using socket.io. All working nicely.
Converting it to a progressive web app required SSL so I've done that and that's working nicely. The app installs as a web app and works.

My problem is that when I go back to work on new features, the local installation of the app server ignores my secure client requests (On the production system, nginx handles the SSL).

These are the offending lines in the client:

```
const socket_url = 'https://' + url.hostname + ':' + port;
const socket = openSocket(socket_url, {query: 'clientId=' + clientId, secure: true});
```

I *could* edit the relevant line in the client conditionally on production versus local development but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ideas for dealing with the test environment vs. production environment issue:

1. You could get a self-signed certificate and use it locally on your https server and have your test browser trust it.  Then, you run https locally.  You will, of course, have to adapt your server code to be an https server also when run in the test environment.
2. You could set up your own NGINX locally with a self-signed certificate and have it provide the same https role that you have in production.
3. When running locally, your server could generate a slightly different web page that inserts `http://` instead of `https://` in the code you show in your question so the client would just automatically use the desired protocol (https in production and http in test).  This could be done with a template engine or could be done manually with search/replace when serving the relevant script.
4. The client-side Javascript could use `location.protocol` instead of a hard code `https` which will then automatically use the protocol that the web page was loaded from which could then be either http or https.  So, if the web page is loaded via http, then socket.io would use http.  If the web page was loaded via https, then socket.io would use https.

Comment: #4 Using the protocol parameter on the client is the go. It solves the problem and is clear and concise.